# [HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I have ASP.net MVC5 application where I am getting error saying `__RequestVerificationToken` not preset. how ever I have `[HttpPost] [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` in my controller in post method and also added `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` when the form begins as seen in below image. In the form like this how do I add  `__RequestVerificationToken` where there is no input tag? `machinekey` is added in web config for to decrypt the antiforgery-token

[image]